# SSIS package validation error - flat file destination has no ID

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, oledb, flat-file

i have a OLE DB SQL Command with a flat file destination and have added to column headers to the flat file but when executing package I get the below issue. is this because I have 2 extra columns in flat file?

[image]

Comment: can u snip mappings of OLEDB to flat file please

Comment: Follow custom properties of Flatfile using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/flat-file-custom-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your package got corrupted.   Your best bet is to drop and re-create the flat-file Destination Connection Manager, and then re-add the connection to the Destination.

Comment: This absolutely could happen, especially if you are copying and pasting Flat File Connection containers

Comment: I think you were right. I dropped and recreated and works. thank you for your help

Comment: @DrHouseofSQL its means better recreate the new package?